# Replacing Google Sheet row values when message is edited in Telegram Bot using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, telegram-bot

I want to replace the values in the row when I edit a message on my telegram bot chat

How can I make use of the message_id to locate the row of values and directly replace it when the message has been edited?

```
function doPost(e) {
  var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);

  var id = contents.message.from.id;
  var name = contents.message.chat.first_name;
  var text = encodeURIComponent(contents.message.text);
  var textstring = text.toString().replaceAll("%20", " ").replaceAll("%0A", "\n");
  var messageid = contents.message.message_id
  
  var dateNow = new Date;
  var dd = dateNow.getDate();
  var mm = dateNow.getMonth() + 1;
  var yyyy = dateNow.getFullYear()
  var hhmmss = dateNow.getHours() + ":" + dateNow.getMinutes() + ":" + dateNow.getSeconds();
  var formatDate = dd + "/" + mm + "/" + yyyy + " " + hhmmss;

  if (textstring.startsWith('/')) {
    console.log("Command Line");
    var answer = "[Command in development]";
    sendMessage(id, answer);
  }
  else {
    var answer = "Added: " + text;
    sendMessage(id, answer);
    sheet.appendRow([messageid, formatDate, id, name, textstring]);
  }

}
```

First row is the initial message and second row is the intended outcome of the edited message

[Outcome.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Npiao.png)

Answer (score 0):

You get all the ids and find the array index. Then if it is found you insert "over" the row. Else append:

```
function doPost(e) {
  var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);

  var id = contents.message.from.id;
  var name = contents.message.chat.first_name;
  var text = encodeURIComponent(contents.message.text);
  var textstring = text.toString().replaceAll("%20", " ").replaceAll("%0A", "\n");
  var messageid = contents.message.message_id

  var dateNow = new Date;
  var dd = dateNow.getDate();
  var mm = dateNow.getMonth() + 1;
  var yyyy = dateNow.getFullYear()
  var hhmmss = dateNow.getHours() + ":" + dateNow.getMinutes() + ":" + dateNow.getSeconds();
  var formatDate = dd + "/" + mm + "/" + yyyy + " " + hhmmss;

  if (textstring.startsWith('/')) {
    console.log("Command Line");
    var answer = "[Command in development]";
    sendMessage(id, answer);
  }
  else {
    var answer = "Added: " + text;
    sendMessage(id, answer);

    const ids = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat()
    const index = ids.indexOf(messageid)

    const dataArray = [messageid, formatDate, id, name, textstring]

    //If the id is not found then it returns -1. So this updates. Arrays are 0 index to we need to + 1 to get the right row.
    if (index >= 0) {
      sheet.getRange(index + 1, 1, 1, dataArray.length).setValues([dataArray])
      //Else insert.
    } else {
      sheet.appendRow(dataArray)
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Would it affect the id because they have been assigned a number already?

https://imgur.com/tEUAHeA
https://imgur.com/a/hFW04bi

Comment: Maybe i'm missing a line to fetch the data from google sheets when an edit is being made on telegram

Comment: I just assumed that the messageId would be the same. If not you need to find a way to make a id so you can lookup the row.

Comment: Messageid is assigned by the bot, it jumps by 2 because when the bot replies for 'var answer = "Added: " + text; ', it is counted as a message as well in the conversation

Comment: How should i do it such that it will trace the messageid (unique ID) to identify the row so that it can replace that row with new set of values?

Comment: Well that was not in your post: `How can I make use of the message_id to locate the row` What would be the unique id then? The method is the same if you have the unique id in the sheet.

Comment: the messageid is considered a unique ID right? 
sorry im quite rusty with this, havent touched programming for 5 years, just recently encountered a situation that requires me to do it

Comment: Yes, I'ts not programming but some logic. If you want to replace data you first need to find the data you want te replace, that you can do with a "key" to find where the original data is.